# im4java Convert svg to png, keep transparent background

Tags: java, imagemagick, im4java

I'm using the im4java library to convert svg files to png files. I want the transparent backgrounds to remain transparent but they always become white. This is the operation I'm using:

```
IMOperation hdpiOperation = new IMOperation();
hdpiOperation.addImage();
hdpiOperation.background("none");
hdpiOperation.addImage();
```

If I manually try with ImageMagick from the commandline using this command it does work:

```
convert -background none a.svg b.png
```

Any ideas?

Comment: either im4java picks alternative `convert` executable or it is susceptable to option order (try to move `background("none")` method one line up.

Comment: The issue was the order! I thought that I had to add the Image first. ( how can I accept your answer on stackoverflow? )

Comment: posted comment as an answer; but variety of imagemagick builds drives me crazy (mine does work properly in both cases and even without `-background` option) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *im4java* appends parameters in method execution order, you can move `hdpiOperation.background("none")` call before image placeholders to mimic working 'raw' command:

```
hdpiOperation.background("none");
hdpiOperation.addImage();
hdpiOperation.addImage();
```